# Able to write file but not read from a network location

Tags: vb.net, file-io, network-share

I have following network location

```
Dim myfolder As String = "\\10.0.0.90\myfolder\"
```

I am able to create a new file in this folder using following code:

```
File.Create (myfolder)
```

But when I try to read contents of this folder using code below I get error.

**Code**

```
Dim orderedFiles = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(myfolder).GetFiles()
```

**Error**

> The system detected a possible attempt to compromise security. Please
>   ensure that you can contact the server that authenticated you.

File writing is being done by ASP.Net page while reading is done from Windows Service. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Not a LAN, right ?? and did you check the permission ??

Comment: You could have write but not read permissions on the folder?

Comment: @MattWilko I have both permissions.

Comment: Does this MS article help ? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938457

Comment: I used this for something similar. It's a winform application but same principles. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43091/Connect-to-a-UNC-Path-with-Credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Service was running as "Local System". I right click on it, went into properties and changed the "Log on as" to some user account and now it can access network folder.